# Criei uma função em Python, mas ela não é executada

Tags: python, funções

Estava estudando sobre a linguagem Python e, como teste, fiz um jogo de Jokenpô.

Para fazer com que ele reiniciasse, vi que teria que colocá-lo dentro de uma função para no final retornar para a mesma e reiniciar o programa, porém, por algum motivo, quando eu coloco o programa dentro de uma função ele simplesmente não retorna nada quando eu rodo ele.

Abaixo mostro o programa no estado atual, o problema começou a ocorrer quando inseri o programa em uma função.

```
#Jokenpô 
from random import randint
import time

def jokenpo():
    player = int(input('Digite 1 para PEDRA \nDigite 2 para PAPEL \nDigite 3 para TESOURA\n'))
    machine = randint(1, 3)

    if player == 1:
        print('Jo')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Ken')
        time.sleep(1) 
        print('Pô!')
        print('Você escolheu pedra.')
        if machine == 1:
            print('A máquina escolheu Pedra, vocês empataram.')
        elif machine == 2:
            print('A máquina escolheu Papel, você perdeu.')
        elif machine == 3:
            print('A máquina escolheu Tesoura, você ganhou')
    if player == 2:
        print('Jo')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Ken')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Pô!')
        print('Você escolheu papel.')
        if machine == 1:
            print('A máquina escolheu Pedra, você ganhou.')
        elif machine == 2:
            print('A máquina escolheu Papel, vocês empataram.')
        elif machine == 3:
            print('A máquina escolheu Tesoura, você perdeu.')
    if player == 3:
        print('Jo')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Ken')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Pô!')
        print('Você escolheu tesoura')
        if machine == 1:
            print('A máquina escolheu Pedra, você perdeu.')
        elif machine == 2:
            print('A máquina escolheu Papel, você ganhou.')
        elif machine == 3:
            print('A máquina escolheu Tesoura, vocês empataram')
```

Comment: E quando você chamou a função `jokenpo` para executá-la?

Comment: Como assim? Como faço para chamá-la? Meu objetivo é fazer o programa dar a opção de reiniciar sabe, tipo um ''Deseja jogar novamente?'' e não fechar o prompt assim que terminar a execução.

Comment: Você sabe o que é uma função e como funciona? Você apenas declarou a função, mas ela não será executada até você chamá-la. Leia mais em [Defining functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: Ah sim, eu devo chamá-la após a declaração, havia ignorado completamente isso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Ridolfi, executei o código por aqui e está tudo tranquilo, acredito que o que esteja faltando são duas informações que seriam pertinentes para o seu código:

- incluir o `# coding:utf-8` no cabeçalho do script: pois você está utilizando alguns caracteres especiais no decorrer do código. E este é o padrão que temos do `python` que fica responsável por reconhecer os mesmos, e realmente pode apresentar alguns quando for realizar a execução.
- Outra coisa importante é você chamar a função `jokenpo()` que criou, um modo útil para isso, é utilizar o seguinte escopo de código:

  ```
  if __name__ == "__main__": 
       jokenpo()
  ```

Ao executar o mesmo código que postou aqui, com as alterações que realizei, obtive o resultado no console:

```
Digite 1 para PEDRA
Digite 2 para PAPEL
Digite 3 para TESOURA
2
Jo
Ken
Pô!
Você escolheu papel.
A máquina escolheu Papel, vocês empataram.
```

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado

Comment: A informação de codificação só é necessária no Python 2. Para a versão 3, é assumido UTF-8 por padrão, vide [PEP 3120](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/).

Answer (score 3):

O erro que faz com que seu código não seja executado é o fato de você nunca ter chamado a função que declarou. Adicione ao final do arquivo para resolver:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
     jokenpo()
```

Veja mais sobre definições de funções em [Defining functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) na documentação oficial.

Porém, há muito código repetido; perceba que seu programa possui 3 condições e o código dentro delas é praticamente o mesmo. Há maneiras de simplificar isso. Por exemplo, você pode definir uma [enumeração](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) para representar as opções do jogo:

```
from enum import Enum

class Jokenpo(Enum):
    pedra = 1
    papel = 2
    tesoura = 3
```

Você solicita ao jogador a opção dele e sorteia a do computador:

```
voce = Jokenpo(int(input('Número de 1 a 3: ')))
computador = Jokenpo(randint(1, 3))
```

Verifica quem ganhou:

```
if voce.value > computador.value or (voce.value, computador.value) == (1, 3):
    resultado = 'venceu'
elif voce.value == computador.value:
    resultado = 'empatou'
else:
    resultado = 'perdeu'
```

E, finalmente, exibe o resultado:

```
print(f'Você {resultado} escolhendo {voce.name} contra {computador.name}')
```

O código, então, ficaria:

```
from enum import Enum
from random import randint

class Jokenpo(Enum):
    pedra = 1
    papel = 2
    tesoura = 3

voce = Jokenpo(int(input('Número de 1 a 3: ')))
computador = Jokenpo(randint(1, 3))

if voce.value > computador.value or (voce.value, computador.value) == (1, 3):
    resultado = 'venceu'
elif voce.value == computador.value:
    resultado = 'empatou'
else:
    resultado = 'perdeu'

print(f'Você {resultado} escolhendo {voce.name} contra {computador.name}')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ThriftyUnawareTexts)</sup>

Perceba que para definir quem ganhou eu verifiquei quem escolheu o maior valor; 2 (papel) vence de 1 (pedra), enquanto 3 (tesoura) vence de 2 (papel). A única exceção é 1 (pedra) vencendo 3 (tesoura), que fiz manualmente.

Ficaria:

```
>>> Número de 1 a 3: 3
Você venceu escolhendo tesoura contra papel
```

Answer (score 0):

Você definiu a função `jokenpo()` mas não a chamou, então ela não será executada até que seja chamada. Adicione o seguinte ao final do seu código:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    jokenpo()
```

O fragmento de código acima serve justamente para chamar a função. A partir do momento que adicionei aqui, o código rodou normalmente, conforme pode ser visto na imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código ficou assim:

```
#Jokenpô 
from random import randint
import time
def jokenpo():
    player = int(input('Digite 1 para PEDRA \nDigite 2 para PAPEL \nDigite 3 para TESOURA\n'))
    machine = randint(1, 3)
    if player == 1:
        print('Jo')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Ken')
        time.sleep(1) 
        print('Pô!')
        print('Você escolheu pedra.')
        if machine == 1:
            print('A máquina escolheu Pedra, vocês empataram.')
        elif machine == 2:
            print('A máquina escolheu Papel, você perdeu.')
        elif machine == 3:
            print('A máquina escolheu Tesoura, você ganhou')
    if player == 2:
        print('Jo')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Ken')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Pô!')
        print('Você escolheu papel.')
        if machine == 1:
            print('A máquina escolheu Pedra, você ganhou.')
        elif machine == 2:
            print('A máquina escolheu Papel, vocês empataram.')
        elif machine == 3:
            print('A máquina escolheu Tesoura, você perdeu.')
    if player == 3:
        print('Jo')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Ken')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Pô!')
        print('Você escolheu tesoura')
        if machine == 1:
            print('A máquina escolheu Pedra, você perdeu.')
        elif machine == 2:
            print('A máquina escolheu Papel, você ganhou.')
        elif machine == 3:
            print('A máquina escolheu Tesoura, vocês empataram')
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    jokenpo()
```